# ExecuteScript в только что открытой вкладке через Windows.create

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension, firefox-extension

```
browser.windows.create({
        url: "google.com",
    }, function (window) {
        var tabid = window.tabs[0].id;
        var makeItGreen = 'document.body.style.border = "20px solid green"';
        browser.tabs.executeScript(
            tabid, {
                code: makeItGreen
            });
```

Код никак не хочет работать, останавливается на открытии окна, причем если в консоли запустить этот же код, но разделить на 2 части то все получается, если я правильно понимаю, то это потому что колбэк начинает выполняться, когда само окно открылось, но вкладка еще не загружена, но тогда возникает вопрос как выполнять код после того как вкладка загрузилась.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы понимаете все верно. После открытия вкладки необходимо дождаться ее полной загрузки. В этом поможет событие [browser.tabs.onUpdated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/onUpdated).

Тактика такова: при создании вкладки вы запоминаете ее ID и затем прослушиваете событие полной загрузки всех вкладок с помощью onUpdated. 
Как только ID совпадает - выполняете код.

```
// createdTabId - ID вкладки, созданой с помощью browser.windows.create
browser.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo) {
    if(changeInfo.status === 'complete' && tabId === createdTabId) {
       // browser.tabs.executeScript
    }
})
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<script>
win = window.open("http://google.com");
win.opener.addEventListener('load', function (event) {
    console.log(win); //Окно окна
    console.log(event); //Объект события
    console.log(win.document); //Но доступа у вас не будет
});
</script>
```